# Interpolating monthly time series to daily

Tags: r, interpolation

I have a dataset containing monthly averages of x

```
Day Month x
1     1   1.2
2     1   1.2
3     1   1.2
4     1   1.2
5     1   1.2
6     1   1.2
.
.
.
1    2   4.2
2    2   4.2
3    2   4.2
.
.
```

and I would like to interpolate these values to get a daily value. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what exactly do you want to achieve? Also, show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Can you `dput` your data also?

Comment: here I have found an answer to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062408/interpolate-extend-quarterly-to-monthly-series