# #R - Split Quarterly data into monthly data using R

Tags: r

Please see the sample data below.

I want to convert the quarterly sale data (with a start date and end date) into monthly sale data.

For example:

- Data set A-Row 1 will be split into Data set B- Row 1, 2 and 3 for June, July and August separately and the sale will be pro rata based on number of days in that month, all other columns will be the same;
- Data set A-Row 2 will pick up what was left in Row 1 (which ends in 5/9/2017) and formed a complete September.

Is there an efficient way to execute this, the actual data is a csv file with 100K x 15 data size, which will be split to approximately 300K x 15 new data set for monthly analysis.

Some key characteristic from sample question data includes:

1. The start day for the first quarterly sales data is the day that customer joins, so it could be any day;
2. All sales will be quarterly but in various days between 90, 91, or 92 days, but it is also possible to have imcomplete quarterly sale data as customer leave in the quarter.

Sample Question:

```
  Customer.ID Country       Type Sale Start..Date  End.Date Days
1           1      US Commercial   91   7/06/2017 5/09/2017   91
2           1      US Commerical   92   6/09/2017 6/12/2017   92
3           2      US     Casual   25  10/07/2017 3/08/2017   25
4           3      UK Commercial   64   7/06/2017 9/08/2017   64
```

Sample Answer:

```
   Customer.ID Country       Type Sale Start.Date   End.Date Days
1           1      US Commercial   24  7/06/2017 30/06/2017   24
2           1      US Commercial   31  1/07/2017 31/07/2017   31
3           1      US Commercial   31  1/08/2017 31/08/2017   31
4           1      US Commercial   30  1/09/2017 30/09/2017   30
5           1      US Commercial   31  1/10/2017 31/10/2017   31
6           1      US Commercial   30  1/11/2017 30/11/2017   30
7           1      US Commercial    6  1/12/2017  6/12/2017    6
8           2      US     Casual   22 10/07/2017 31/07/2017   22
9           2      US     Casual    3  1/08/2017  3/08/2017    3
10          3      UK Commercial   24  7/06/2017 30/06/2017   24
11          3      UK Commercial   31  1/07/2017 31/07/2017   31
12          3      UK Commercial    9  1/08/2017  9/08/2017    9
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062408/interpolate-extend-quarterly-to-monthly-series

Comment: Thanks CIAndrews, but I dont think it is the same question. I did search across the web including stack overflow, the only close answer is done by excel vba, but it always ended up frozen given the actual size.

Comment: In your sample answer, the extension is done per country, per type? And is it correct that the customer id should be max 3?

Comment: Hi, the customer ID is unique across all country and type, but each customer ID may be multiple rows of data hence the quarterly data, and the customer ID is not max at 3, actually 100s of thousands difference customer id in the actual data. Either Country and Type could be the extention, the main purpose for both of them to show in the data is for analysis phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran CIAndrews' code. It seems to work for the most part, but it is very slow when run on a dataset with 10,000 rows. I eventually cancelled the execution after a few minutes of waiting. There's also an issue with the number of days: For example, July has 31 days, but the `days` variable only shows thirty. It's true that 31-1 = 30, but the first day should be counted as well.

The code below only takes about 21 seconds on my 2015 MacBook Pro (not including data generation), and takes care of the other problem, too.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)


# generate data -------------------------------------------------------------

set.seed(666)

# assign variables
customer <- sample.int(n = 2000, size = 10000, replace = T)
country <- sample(c("US", "UK", "DE", "FR", "IS"), 10000, replace = T)
type <- sample(c("commercial", "casual", "other"), 10000, replace = T)
start <- sample(seq(dmy("7/06/2011"), today(), by = "day"), 10000, replace = T)
days <- sample(85:105, 10000, replace = T)
end <- start + days
sale <- sample(500:3000, 10000, replace = T)

# generate dataframe of artificial data
df_quarterly <- tibble(customer, country, type, sale, start, end, days)



# split quarters into months ----------------------------------------------

# initialize empty list with length == nrow(dataframe)
list_date_dfs <- vector(mode = "list", length = nrow(df_quarterly))

# for-loop generates new dates and adds as dataframe to list
for (i in 1:length(list_date_dfs)) {

    # transfer dataframe row to variable `row`
    row <- df_quarterly[i,]

    # correct end date so split successful when interval doesn't cover full month
    end_corr <- row$end + day(row$start) - day(row$end)

    # use lubridate to compute first and last days of relevant months
    m_start <- seq(row$start, end_corr, by = "month") %>% 
        floor_date(unit = "month")
    m_end <- m_start + days_in_month(m_start) - 1

    # replace first and last elements with original dates
    m_start[1] <- row$start
    m_end[length(m_end)] <- row$end

    # compute the number of days per month as well as sales per month
    # correct difference by adding 1
    m_days <- as.integer(m_end - m_start) + 1
    m_sale <- (row$sale / sum(m_days)) * m_days

    # add tibble to list
    list_date_dfs[[i]] <- tibble(customer = row$customer,
                                 country = row$country,
                                 type = row$type,
                                 sale = m_sale,
                                 start = m_start,
                                 end = m_end,
                                 days = m_days
    )
}

# bind dataframe list elements into single dataframe
df_monthly <- bind_rows(list_date_dfs)
```

Comment: Thanks @gersht, this is very clean and swift.

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty as it uses multiple functions and loops, since it consists out of multiple operations:

```
# Creating the dataset
library(tidyr)
customer <- c(1,1,2,3)
country <- c("US","US","US","UK")
type <- c("Commercial","Commercial","Casual","Commercial")
sale <- c(91,92,25,64)
Start <- as.Date(c("7/06/2017","6/09/2017","10/07/2017","7/06/2017"),"%d/%m/%Y")
Finish <- as.Date(c("5/09/2017","6/12/2017","3/08/2017","9/08/2017"),"%d/%m/%Y")
days <- c(91,92,25,64)
df <- data.frame(customer,country, type,sale, Start,Finish,days)

# Function to split per month
library(zoo)
addrowFun <- function(y){
    temp <- do.call("rbind", by(y, 1:nrow(y), function(x) with(x, {
    eom <- as.Date(as.yearmon(Start), frac = 1)
    if (eom < Finish)
       data.frame(customer, country, type, Start = c(Start, eom+1), Finish = c(eom, Finish))
    else x
    })))
    return(temp)
 }
loop <- df
for(i in 1:10){ #not all months are split up at once
   loop <- addrowFun(loop)
}
# Calculating the days per month
loop$days <- as.numeric(difftime(loop$Finish,loop$Start, units="days"))

# Creating the function to get the monthly sales pro rata
sumFun <- function(x){
   tempSum <- df[x$Start >= df$Start & x$Finish <= df$Finish & df$customer == x$customer,]
   totalSale <- sum(tempSum$sale)
   totalDays <- sum(tempSum$days)
   return(x$days / totalDays * totalSale)
 }

for(i in 1:length(loop$customer)){
   loop$sale[i] <- sumFun(loop[i,])
}  

loop
```

Comment: Thanks Mate, for the detail answer, I will have a look and get back to you soon.

Comment: Hi, your codes can replicate the sample answer very quickly, however, when I try to apply the extract of actual file, it returns error at the first loop, could you please help check what went wrong, I have the codes attached.

Comment: Hi, if there are multiple variables that need pro rata, where should I modify the original code to make it work.. e.g. instead of sales that needs pro rata, what if there are costs, revenue, usage etc that all needs to pro rata treatment.

Comment: I can approach this by adding more 'sumFun' against different variables, is there a way to simplify the process?

Comment: Hi, could you please help explain the following codes.#by(y, 1:nrow(y), function(x) with(x, {
        eom <- as.Date(as.yearmon(start), frac = 1)
        if (eom < finish)
            data.table(Invoice, site_identifier, start = c(start, eom+1), finish = c(eom, finish))
        else x
    })))# When I applied the data, it simply takes too long and I am trying to swap with rbindlist, bind_rows etc and test if it can speed up the process but all of them comes back with argument must not be a 'by'.

Answer (score 0):

CiAndrews,

Thanks for the help and patience. I have managed to get the answer with small change. I have replace the "rbind" with "rbind.fill" from "plyr" package and everything runs smoothly after that.

Please see the head of sample2.csv below

```
    customer   country    type     sale      Start      Finish     days
1 43108181108    US    Commercial  3330    17/11/2016  24/02/2017   99
2 43108181108    US    Commercial  2753    24/02/2017  23/05/2017   88
3 43108181108    US    Commercial  3043    13/02/2018  18/05/2018   94
4 43108181108    US    Commercial  4261    23/05/2017  18/08/2017   87
5 43103703637    UK    Casual      881     4/11/2016   15/02/2017   103
6 43103703637    UK    Casual      1172    26/07/2018  1/11/2018    98
```

Please see the codes below:

```
library(tidyr)

#read data and change the start and finish to data type

data <- read.csv("Sample2.csv")
data$Start <- as.Date(data$Start, "%d/%m/%Y")
data$Finish <- as.Date(data$Finish, "%d/%m/%Y")
customer <- data$customer
country <- data$country
days <- data$days
Finish <- data$Finish
Start <- data$Start
sale <- data$sale
type <- data$type
df <- data.frame(customer, country, type, sale, Start, Finish, days)

# Function to split per month

library(zoo)
library(plyr)
addrowFun <- function(y){
    temp <- do.call("rbind.fill", by(y, 1:nrow(y), function(x) with(x, {
        eom <- as.Date(as.yearmon(Start), frac = 1)
        if (eom < Finish)
            data.frame(customer, country, type, Start = c(Start, eom+1), Finish = c(eom, Finish))
        else x
    })))
    return(temp)
}
loop <- df
for(i in 1:10){ #not all months are split up at once
    loop <- addrowFun(loop)
}

# Calculating the days per month

loop$days <- as.numeric(difftime(loop$Finish,loop$Start, units="days"))

# Creating the function to get the monthly sales pro rata

sumFun <- function(x){
    tempSum <- df[x$Start >= df$Start & x$Finish <= df$Finish & df$customer == x$customer,]
    totalSale <- sum(tempSum$sale)
    totalDays <- sum(tempSum$days)
    return(x$days / totalDays * totalSale)
}

for(i in 1:length(loop$customer)){
    loop$sale[i] <- sumFun(loop[i,])
}  

loop
```

Comment: In the example code there is `Start` and `Finish`, while your sample data has `End` instead of `Finish`. When changing either all `Finish` to `End` or vice versa, the code runs

Comment: Hi, I have changed all End to Finish in the code, but still end up with the same error, the error only occur in the first loop, could it be the for(i in 1:10) that does not fit the actual sample.

Comment: Are you sure your `data` has only those columns or actually more?

Comment: Hi, there are total of 7 columns: "customer", "country", "type", "sale", "start", "finish" and "days", but I import this from the sample csv which generate a first index column, and the sample size has 300 rows.

Comment: Could you please clarify what the 1:10 is for in the first loop.