# Time series interpolation: monthly data to certain day frequency data

Tags: r, datetime, merge, interpolation, linear-interpolation

I have time series data containing monthly observations. I now want the given interpolate monthly values (preferred linear, cubic is fine) according to a data sequence (for eg. 15-day sequence). The intermediate goal should be to create a data frame with the date as the index and missing values for all the monthly observations.

We can consider these values starting from the start of the month, for eg. "Sep-16" indicate 2016-09-01. So we need to change the date format as well.

```
head(df)
#     date      sp1
# 1 Sep-16  2.58868
# 2 Oct-16  0.51014
# 3 Nov-16 -0.81165
# 4 Dec-16 -0.52575
# 5 Jan-17 -0.93884
# 6 Feb-17 -1.95657
```

What I want to do is to get sp1 values for the following date sequence:

```
DateSeq <- seq(as.Date("2016-09-01"), as.Date("2020-07-30"), by=15)
```

I found a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062408/interpolate-extend-quarterly-to-monthly-series%20but%20it%20seems%20to%20be%20different.)

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

### Data

```
df <- data.frame(date=c("Sep-16", "Oct-16", "Nov-16", "Dec-16", "Jan-17", "Feb-17", 
                        "Mar-17", "Apr-17", "May-17" , "Jun-17", "Jul-17", "Aug-17", "Sep-17", "Oct-17", 
                        "Nov-17", "Dec-17", "Jan-18", "Feb-18", "Mar-18", "Apr-18", "May-18", 
                        "Jun-18", "Jul-18", "Aug-18", "Sep-18", "Oct-18", "Nov-18", "Dec-18", 
                        "Jan-19", "Feb-19", "Mar-19", "Apr-19", "May-19", "Jun-19", "Jul-19", 
                        "Aug-19", "Sep-19", "Oct-19", "Nov-19", "Dec-19",  "Jan-20", "Feb-20", 
                        "Mar-20", "Apr-20" , "May-20", "Jun-20", "Jul-20", "Aug-20"),
                 sp1=c(2.58868 , 0.51014 , -0.81165, -0.52575, -0.93884, -1.95657, 
                       1.65728,  0.00522, -0.11818, -1.14689, -1.24314, -0.50178, 
                       -1.60286, 0.04624, -0.37180, -0.16875, -0.95811, -0.79433, 
                       -0.64041, -1.27894, -0.75469, -0.89954, -1.51727, -0.03980, 
                       -0.76522,  0.11057,  0.13922, 0.45866, -0.70275, -1.37621,  0.89521, 
                       -1.41637, -0.25305, -1.29723, 1.41120, -0.98463, -0.93980, -1.50555, 
                       -1.37363, -2.33455, -0.73567, 0.30003,  1.38937,  1.56948, 
                       -0.23575, -0.52387,  0.97928,  0.40289))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you would add a day, e.g. the first of the month to the dates and convert `as.Date`. Then `merge` with an `expand.grid` on the `seq.Date` `ds`, and `approx` the values to linearly interpolate. I use `sp2` to demonstrate, but you can overwrite `sp1`. Finally `subset` the data frame on the `ds`.

```
df$date <- as.Date(paste0(df$date, '-01'), '%b-%y-%d')
ds <- seq.Date(as.Date("2016-09-01"), as.Date("2020-07-30"), by=15)
df <- merge(df, expand.grid(date=ds), all=TRUE)
df$sp2 <- approx(df$sp1, xout=seq_along(df$date))$y

res <- subset(df, date %in% ds)

head(res)
#         date     sp1         sp2
# 1 2016-09-01 2.58868  2.58868000
# 2 2016-09-16      NA  1.54941000
# 3 2016-10-01 0.51014  0.51014000
# 4 2016-10-16      NA  0.06954333
# 5 2016-10-31      NA -0.37105333
# 7 2016-11-15      NA -0.71635000

tail(res)
#           date sp1      sp2
# 132 2020-05-13  NA -0.33179
# 133 2020-05-28  NA -0.42783
# 135 2020-06-12  NA -0.02282
# 136 2020-06-27  NA  0.47823
# 138 2020-07-12  NA  0.78715
# 139 2020-07-27  NA  0.59502
```

**Notice,** that `"2020-07-30"` is not included in the sequence of 15 days, starting at Sep 1, 2016.

### Visualization

```
with(df, plot(date, sp2, type='o', ylim=range(df$sp1, na.rm=TRUE)))
with(df, points(date, sp1, pch=16))
legend('topright', pch=c(16, 1), legend=c('measured', 'interpolated'), horiz=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @jay.sf. What I am after here is get sp values only for the date sequence:         
DateSeq <- seq(as.Date("2016-09-01"), as.Date("2020-07-30"), by=15)

Comment: thanks @jay.sf. But when I subset a larger data frame containing the data, (or slice date and sp1 from a much larger data frame), and run the script, it throws the error as: Error in approx(df$sp2, xout = seq_along(df$date)) :   need at least two non-NA values to interpolate.

Comment: @kl40 Not sure, but it appears you used `df$sp2`, and they are all `NA`. Did you check that?